# Show that a particular set is not a limit ordinal (aim is to define ordinal subtraction)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two ordinals with $\beta \leq \alpha$. Define

$$ X:= \{\gamma \in \alpha^{+} : \beta + \gamma \leq \alpha\}.$$

I have shown this is an ordinal. Now I need to show it isn't a limit ordinal, but I'm stuck.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What is $\alpha^+$ for you? (Because in many contexts, that denotes the successor *cardinal* of $|\alpha|$.)

Comment: It is the successor of $\alpha$, namely $\alpha \cup \{ \alpha\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Assume to the contrary, and use the definition of $\beta+\delta$ when $\delta$ is a limit ordinal, to show that $\beta+\delta\leq\alpha$ as well to obtain a contradiction.

Comment: What is otp? Thanks.

Comment: Order type, the unique ordinal isomorphic to the well-ordered set given.

Comment: Ok thanks. If this is what the writer of the exercise intended I would be surprised, as the next part uses this $\gamma$ as 'another' way of doing the problem.

Comment: Well. I didn't write that exercise, and I don't know what you've learned and not learned. So I can't quite tell you what the writer of the exercise had in mind for a solution.

Comment: I expect the intended answer is somehow to show that $\cup X \neq X$ using the concept of supremum.

Comment: (I know it is annoying for me to say it isn't what he intended, sorry).

Comment: Here's a different hint.

Comment: Ah thanks I think I see now. Suppose $X$ is a limit. Then $\beta + X = \cup\{\beta+ \gamma : \gamma \in X \} \leq \alpha$, getting the contradiction that $X \in X$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea.

Comment: Ok thanks you've been very helpful.

Comment: Well, it beats a hard kick in the face!